# Can Outlook tasks be shared without Exchange?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

We work in a small business with no Exchange server (yet).

Is it possible to share Outlook 2010 Tasks between two people without using an Exchange server?

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your email provider and how syncing works.

Have you tried setting up a shared mailbox that everyone can access (as a second mailbox) in Outlook?